# Apache vs Twisted

Tags: python, apache, twisted

I know Twisted is a framework that allows you to do asynchronous non-blocking i/o but I still do not understand how that is different from what Apache server does. If anyone could explain the need for twisted, I would appreciate it..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Twisted is a platform for developing internet applications, for handling the underlying communications and such. It doesn't "do" anything out of the box--you've got to program it.

Apache is an internet application, of sorts. Upon install, you have a working web server which can serve up static and dynamic web pages. Beyond that, it can be extended to do more than that, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

They are two different things, one is a pure WEB server and one is a WEB framework with a builtin event driven servers.

Twisted is good for constructing high-end ad-hoc network services.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, FriendFeed/Facebook just open sourced their custom server and framework: [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/).  Matt Heitzenroder of Apparatus has run an initial comparison test and [looks like Tornado left twisted in the dust](http://www.apparatusproject.org/blog/).

Comment: The numbers you linked to clearly show that Twisted responded faster and handled slightly more requests. Of course this benchmark does not take features into account either.

Answer (score 2):

@alphazero You read that Twisted vs. Tornado benchmark wrong (or you didn't read it at all).  Quote from the article: " Lower mean response time is better." Twisted is *lower*.  People want their webservers to respond with lower (faster) times.

Twisted leaves Tornado in the dust... or, in reality, they differ by a nearly trivial constant factor.